# CloudFormation Magic to Generate A List of ARNs from a List of Account Ids

Tags: aws-cloudformation

In my template, I am passing a `CommaDelimitedList` of account ids as a parameter.

I am hoping to do some `Fn::Join` and/or `Fn::Sub` magic to transform the list as follow:

```
 "Accounts" : {
     "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
     "Default" : "12222234,23333334,1122143234,..."
}

To be used in the template as a list `root` ARN's as :
 [
   "arn:aws:iam::12222234:root"
   "arn:aws:iam::23333334:root"
   "arn:aws:iam::1122143234:root"
 ]
```

Right now I am passing in the full ARNs, so it's working, but it is kluncky.  However the CFN built in functions are proving very hard at doing this.

Any one have ready code for something like this?

Answer (score 16):

I was able to adapt the existing answer by Sam Hammamy to work around the limitation of requiring special handling for the first and last items by using `Fn::Sub`. You can also combine two of the `Join`s.

In YAML:

```
AWS: !Split
  - ','
  - !Sub
    - 'arn:aws:iam::${inner}:root'
    - inner: !Join
      - ':root,arn:aws:iam::'
      - Ref: "Accounts"
```

And in JSON:

```
"Fn::Split": [
    ",", 
    {
        "Fn::Sub": [
            "arn:aws:iam::${rest}:root", 
            {
                "rest": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        ":root,arn:aws:iam::", 
                        { "Ref": "Accounts" }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: this has saved my bacon.  Great little snippet of code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The below works, but it has a strong limitation:

Because of the nature of the `Fn::Join` function, it places the delimitter between the elements of the list. Therefore the first and last element need special handing, as in:

```
"arn:aws:iam::xxxxx,yyyyy,zzzzzz,fffffff:root"

"Principal": {
    "AWS":{
        "Fn::Split" : 
            [",",
                {"Fn::Join" : [",arn:aws:iam::",
                    {
                        "Fn::Split" : 
                            [",",
                                {"Fn::Join" : 
                                  [":root,", {"Ref": "Accounts"}]}
                             ]
                    }
                ]}
            ]
            }
}
```

Not great, but better than previous.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add a couple of years later that @borkl's response above basically worked for me as well, but I had to seek help from AWS support for my case. Thought I'd the learning here.

Note: Parameters are of type CommaDelimitedList

Basically, the process is this:

1. Add something to the first item, let's say 'arn::something:::'
2. Replace the commas with ',arn::something:::'  <-- note the comma
3. Split on commas

I wanted to turn a list of Managed Policy names into arns so:

```
!Split
  - ","
  - -!Sub
    - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/${rest}
    - rest:
        !Join
          - ",arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/"
          - !Ref AWSManagedPolicies
```

Hope this helps somebody, or even me in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `${rest}` doesn't have to be trailing.

I wanted to create an AssumeRolePolicyDocument with Trusts to several accounts and managed to put this one together.

```
!Split:
  - ","
  - !Sub:
      - arn:aws:iam::${rest}:root
      - rest:
          !Join:
            - ":root,arn:aws:iam::"
            - Ref: TrustRelationships
```

This wizardry isn't really documented but it IS a quite useful trick.