# Sub and Join on Comma-Delimited List

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to build an ECS (Fargate) Task Definition that uses a variable number of Environment Variables passed to Command. Each variable name matches a secret in SecretsManager.

I've having trouble combining these functions in a meaningful way. The following code just passes all of the variables to Command as a list of strings.

```
 SpecEnvVars:
   Type: CommaDelimitedList
   Default: "greeting,name,title,rank"
   Description: |
     The Environmental Variables to pull into the container, defined by their
     associated Secrets names

 ContainerDefinitions:
   - Name: !Ref 'ServiceName'
     Command: !Split
       - ','
       - !Join
         - ','
         - !Ref SpecEnvVars
```

However, I need to resolve the items in the list to secrets JSON. Resolving the secrets is done like so:

```
!Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:test/${greeting}}}'
```

How can I integrate Fn::Sub with the Split/Join to return a list of SecretsManager JSON strings?

Answer (score 5):

It took me a while to find the correct combination of Functions but I did it:

```
ContainerDefinitions:
  - Name: !Ref 'ServiceName'
    Command: !Split
      - ','
      - !Sub
        - '{{resolve:secretsmanager:test/${inner}}}'
        - inner: !Join
          - '}},{{resolve:secretsmanager:test/'
          - Ref: "SpecEnvVars"
```

I want to give props to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50060983/9671763 because it actually gave me my answer - I just needed to adapt it for my use-case.