# Cloudformation Combine Sub and Join to get a list

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I am trying to create a list in my Cloudformation template.

Inspired by this post: [Sub and Join on Comma-Delimited List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386102/sub-and-join-on-comma-delimited-list) I have gotten to this idea but it doesnt work as the !Sub line has to be a string...

Error is:

```
Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: STACKNAME, ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined.
```

Any thoughts? Is this even possible?

```
  Accounts:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: Acc1,Acc2,Acc3

  pRedshiftUser:
    Type: String
    Default: arn:redshiftperson

  ...

    Action: sts:AssumeRole
    Condition:
      StringEquals:
        sts:ExternalId: !Split
          - ','
          - !Sub
            - '${pRedshiftUser}/${user}'
            - user: !Join
              - !Sub ',${pRedshiftUser}/'
              - Ref: "Accounts"
```

The idea being I'm trying to create this as the output:

```
  Action: sts:AssumeRole
    Condition:
      StringEquals:
        sts:ExternalId:
          - arn:redshiftperson/user1
          - arn:redshiftperson/user2
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you provided so far? Any errors?

Comment: I have just added the error text to the question.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't achieve what you want with split?

Comment: Seems it might not be possible to do what I want. Split would work if I included the arn e.g. [arn:redshiftperson/user1,arn:redshiftperson/user2] My goal was to try and not have to include the arn:redshiftperson in every item.

Comment: You could create your own CloudFormation macro if you really wanted such a functionality. But what you want is not natively supported.

Comment: I update the answer with info about macro and custom resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't do this. `Delimiter` in `Join` must be [explicit string](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html#intrinsic-function-reference-join-supportedfunctions).

> For the Fn::Join delimiter, you **can't use any functions**. You must specify a string value.

So you can't use `Sub` in `Delimiter`.

The only way would to create a custom [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CloudFormation. In both ways, you would need to develop a lambda function to handle the transformation of your data to desired format.