# Using the Cloudformation Join function with a CommaDelimitedList Parameter to build IAM ARNs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have been trying to build out a Bucket Policy to allow actions on a centralised account in CloudFormation to IAM Roles in a series of other accounts that share the same pattern - I.E:

`arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/my-role`

`arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/my-role`

I have found the following example, which gets me close, but not quite close enough:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50060983/1736704

Below is an Example of code that works:

```
Parameters:
  MyAccounts:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: '111111111111,222222222222'
  MyBucket:
    Type: String
    Default: my-bucket

Resources:
  MyBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref MyBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: MyRoleAllow
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              AWS: !Split
                - ','
                - !Sub
                  - 'arn:aws:iam::${inner}:role/my-role'
                  - inner: !Join
                    - ':role/my-role,arn:aws:iam::'
                    - Ref: 'MyAccounts'
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject              
            Resource: !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${MyBucket}/*
```

What I would like to be able to do is make the role name a parameter.  When I attempt to do that, no matter how I structure the `!Join` function, I get errors.

If I modify the above code and have `my-role` as a string parameter called `RoleName`, and expand the `!Join`, it returns an error.  The full modified code that doesn't work:

```
Parameters:
  MyAccounts:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: '111111111111,222222222222'
  RoleName
    Type: String
    Default: my-role
  MyBucket:
    Type: String
    Default: my-bucket

Resources:
  MyBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref MyBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: MyRoleAllow
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              AWS: !Split
                - ','
                - !Sub
                  - 'arn:aws:iam::${inner}:role/my-role'
                  - inner: !Join
                    - ''
                    - - ':role/'
                      - !Ref 'RoleName'
                      - ',arn:aws:iam::'
                      - Ref: 'Accounts'
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject              
            Resource: !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${MyBucket}/*
```

This is the error message I am getting:
`Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined.`

In the modified code, it is the `Ref: 'Accounts'` that is causing the issue, but I am confused why, because it works in the original code.

Edit:
The inputs I would like to use are:

```
Parameters:
  MyAccounts:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: '111111111111,222222222222'
  RoleName
    Type: String
    Default: my-role
  MyBucket:
    Type: String
    Default: my-bucket
```

My expected output (a S3 Bucket Policy) would look like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "MyRoleAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/my-role",
                    "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/my-role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me if what I am trying to achieve is possible?  If so, how can I modify my code to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to achieve? What are the inputs and expected output?

Comment: @Marcin I have updated the original post with expected inputs and outputs

Comment: I have fully expanded the modified code that doesn't work as expected.  Apologies if I have created confusion

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70475459/3390419

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no obvious way of doing this. In the original `Join`:

```
              - inner: !Join
                - ':role/my-role,arn:aws:iam::'
                - Ref: 'MyAccounts'
```

the part `':role/my-role,arn:aws:iam::'` is Join's *delimiter*. From the docs:

> For the Fn::Join delimiter, you cannot use any functions. You **must** specify a **string value**.

In your new `join` you are using empty *delimiter*. You must use `':role/my-role,arn:aws:iam::'` as delimiter, it can't be empty string `''`.

Ideally you would use:

```
              - inner: !Join
                - !Sub ':role/${RoleName},arn:aws:iam::'
                - Ref: 'MyAccounts'
```

but this will also not work due to the *delimiter* **not** being a string.

I think the best workaround to this issue would be to use basic find-and-replace  [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html), especially if you want to use this pattern of role and accounts combo in multiple templates.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation.  In my haste I was hoping that an empty string was still considered a string.

Comment: It is, but the expansion work because you have non-empty string there. But anyway, I would recommend against using such solution anyway. Its difficult to understand, debug and non-intuitive.  In my experience, tricks like this will only lead to problems in the long run.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I was just trying to avoid using a macro.  The other option I was thinking of was using the full IAM ARN's in the CommaDelimitedList parameter.  At max, I would have 20 accounts that I would be doing this for (currently 2!), so I might scrape in the byte limit

Comment: Macro can be cross account, so you could have just one central account for this or other macros. But anyway if you find some suited solution for this, please let me know. Interesting problem and curious on what would be the best path for you to take on this.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Marcin.  I need to move forward on this, so the list of full ARN's as a CSV with a string type is what I am going with for now.  I can at least split on the comma and have multiple principals.  That being said, I will note potential improvements and hopefully get back to it at some stage.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume I have:

```yaml
Parameters:
  ChildAccounts:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: ""
    Description: Comma delimited list of accounts.
```

If you can cleverly use `!Join`, `!Sub`, and `!Split` you can actually get that to work IF you don't need to sub in any other arguments:

```yaml
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - sts:AssumeRole
    Resource: !Split
      - ','
      - !Sub
        - arn:aws:iam::${MIDDLE_ACOUNTs}:role/ChildAccountRole
        - MIDDLE_ACOUNTs: !Join
          - ':role/ChildAccountRole,arn:aws:iam::'
          - !Ref ChildAccounts
```

However, sadly, in my case I needed to sub a different parameter called `Environment` into each role name and all went to hell with the above approach when I attempted to do that.

So after enough head banging I went with a different approach and decided to add a custom intrinsic function by using [Cloudformation Macros / Transformations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html).

First I needed to deploy a macro. This macro will look in resources of templates for a key called `Tr::ListSub` whose value is a two/three element list (further explained in the example later).

The following CloudFormation will create the macro which we can use. You should deploy this template before using the created macro in a different template.

```yaml
Resources:

  MacroLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: LoggingPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: '*'

  MacroLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: !GetAtt MacroLambdaRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import logging
          from typing import Dict, Union, List
          LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
          LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)
          def render_sub_map(sub_map: Dict, template_param_value: Dict):
              """
              ARGUMENTS:
              `sub_map` example:
                  {
                      "Tr::ListSub": [
                          "${Environment}-${ListSubItem}-${AWS::Account}"
                          ["VALUE1", "VALUE2", "VALUE3"],
                          {
                              "EXAMPLE": "test",
                          }
                      ]
                  }
              RETURNS
              [
                  {"Fn::Sub": ["${Environment}-VALUE1-${AWS::Account}", {"EXAMPLE": "test"}]},
                  {"Fn::Sub": ["${Environment}-VALUE2-${AWS::Account}", {"EXAMPLE": "test"}]},
                  {"Fn::Sub": ["${Environment}-VALUE3-${AWS::Account}", {"EXAMPLE": "test"}]}
              ]
              """
              sub_str = sub_map["Tr::ListSub"][0]
              sub_list = sub_map["Tr::ListSub"][1]
              if isinstance(sub_list, dict):
                  sub_list = template_param_value[sub_list["Ref"]]
              sub_dict = {}
              if len(sub_map["Tr::ListSub"]) == 3:
                  sub_dict = sub_map["Tr::ListSub"][2]
              results = []
              for item in sub_list:
                  new_sub_str = sub_str.replace("${ListSubItem}", item)
                  results.append({
                      "Fn::Sub": [
                          new_sub_str,
                          sub_dict
                      ]
                  })
              return results
          
          def iterate_resources(resources: Dict, template_param_value: Dict) -> None:
              """ Distructive to `fragment`. """
              def _recurse_search(_dict_or_list: Union[Dict, List]):
                  
                  if isinstance(_dict_or_list, dict):
                      for key, val in _dict_or_list.items():
                          if isinstance(val, dict):
                              if "Tr::ListSub" in val:
                                  _dict_or_list[key] = render_sub_map(val, template_param_value)
                              else:
                                  _recurse_search(val)
                          else:
                              _recurse_search(val)
                  elif isinstance(_dict_or_list, list):
                      for item in _dict_or_list:
                          _recurse_search(item)
              _recurse_search(resources)
          
          def handler(event, context):
              LOGGER.info(json.dumps(event, indent=2))
              iterate_resources(event["fragment"]["Resources"], event["templateParameterValues"])
              response = {
                  "status": "success",
                  "fragment": event["fragment"],
                  "requestId": event["requestId"]
              }
              LOGGER.info(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
              return response

  MacroExample:    
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Macro
    Properties:
      Name: ListSubTransform
      Description: Macro to create do a sub expression for each item in a list.
      FunctionName: !GetAtt MacroLambda.Arn

  MacroLambdaLogStream:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub /aws/lambda/${MacroLambda}
      RetentionInDays: 3
```

So lets explain how this macro works. You can see some examples below.

The macro added is called `Tr::ListSub`.

- The first argument is a string such as one you would provide for `!Sub/Fn::Sub` but without the prepended `!Sub`. The string can contain any variable that you could add to a normal `!Sub` such as `${AWS::Account}`; but, to reference each item in the list as it iterates, use `${ListSubItem}`.
- The second argument is the list of items to iterate over. In my example below I `!Ref` a `CommaDelimitedList` parameter.
- The third *optional* argument is a dictionary which is key value pairs which will be added to the generated `!Sub` expressions.

That description is kind of hard to follow so here are a couple examples for reference.

Lets say my CloudFormation has the following:

```json
{
    "Tr::ListSub": [
        "${Environment}-${ListSubItem}-${AWS::Account}"
        ["VALUE1", "VALUE2", "VALUE3"],
        {
            "EXAMPLE": "test",
        }
    ]
}
```

This macro would then swap out that intrinsic with the following:

```json
[
    {"Fn::Sub": ["${Environment}-VALUE1-${AWS::Account}", {"EXAMPLE": "test"}]},
    {"Fn::Sub": ["${Environment}-VALUE2-${AWS::Account}", {"EXAMPLE": "test"}]},
    {"Fn::Sub": ["${Environment}-VALUE3-${AWS::Account}", {"EXAMPLE": "test"}]}
]
```

Full Cloudformation Template Example:

```yaml
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
  ChildAccounts:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: ""
    Description: Comma delimited list of accounts.
Transform:
  - ListSubTransform
Resources:
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-STS-Policy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - sts:AssumeRole
              Resource:
                Tr::ListSub:
                  - arn:aws:iam::${ListSubItem}:role/${Environment}-MetricMolePup
                  - !Ref ChildAccounts
```

This macro isn't bullet proof but does the job unless you try to nest it inside intrinsics in which case AWS will error out before the transform is called.