# Adding multiple Principal values for KMS key

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I want to add multiple Principal values for a KMS key using CloudFormation. This is a snippet of the code:

```
"KmsKeyManager": {
  "Type": "String",
  "Default": "user1,user2,user3"
}
          
"Principal": {
  "AWS": {
    "Fn::Split": [
      ",",
      {
        "Fn::Sub": [
          "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/people/${rest}",
          {
            "rest": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                  "arn:aws:iam::",
                  {
                    "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                  },
                  ":user/people/",
                  {
                    "Ref": "KmsKeyManager"
                  }
                ]
              ...
```

The ARN should be constructed as `arn:aws:iam::12345678:user/people/user1` etc.

The template is accepted in the console, but when running I get the following error:
`Resource handler returned message: "An ARN in the specified key policy is invalid.`

I followed the answer here which resulted in the above error
[CloudFormation Magic to Generate A List of ARNs from a List of Account Ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950222/cloudformation-magic-to-generate-a-list-of-arns-from-a-list-of-account-ids/50060983#50060983)

Any idea where I am going wrong? CloudFormation is new to me, so the alternative is I create with 1 user and add new users manually.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain from the [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950222/cloudformation-magic-to-generate-a-list-of-arns-from-a-list-of-account-ids/). They use the string `":root,arn:aws:iam::"` ***as a delimiter***.

Therefore,

```
"Accounts" : {
     "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
     "Default" : "12222234,23333334,1122143234,..."
}

"rest": {
    "Fn::Join": [
        ":root,arn:aws:iam::", 
        { "Ref": "Accounts" }
    ]
}
```

gives `rest` like this.

```
12222234:root,arn:aws:iam::23333334:root,arn:aws:iam::1122143234
```

and this `rest` is substituted for `${rest}` in `"arn:aws:iam::${rest}:root"`  (This long string will be split finally with `"Fn::Split"`.)

In your case, delimiter will be `"arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/people/"`.

This is also need to be joined:

```
{
  "Fn::Join": [
    "", [
      "arn:aws:iam::",
      {
        "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
      },
      ":user/people/"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The total will be like:

```
"Fn::Sub": [
  "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/people/${rest}",
  {
    "rest": {
      "Fn::Join": [
        "Fn::Join": [
          "", [
            "arn:aws:iam::",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
            },
            ":user/people/"
          ]
        ],
        {
          "Ref": "KmsKeyManager"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so in my case Split is not required? I've tried what you suggested but there's an error in my IDE after the 2nd Join, expecting a comma rather than `:`

Comment: Sorry! It seems we cannot use functions in/as a delimiter. I'm searching for another way, maybe using Lambda but not sure for now. As of Split function, we need it because the result is connected to one string.